# Strategy to develop a web service in JAX WS

Tags: web-services, maven, jax-ws

i'd like your help to designing a wb serice but I don't know  how i can't do this.
In fact my application handles data management clients. My application is developped in struts 1.0, spring, weblogic and build-in maven.
He was asked to me to make an evolution because an external application need to access data such as displaying the address of the client or displaying data bank. For this, it was planned to create a web service to retrieve in real time.
I would like to know the strategy to use for designing a web service. Do I need to create a new Dynamite projet maven + JAX WS to my web service and deploy my war on my weblogic server?
Or they have something else to do ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that this question is related to maven.

Adding a WebService (or RestService) could be quite easy with springframework and apache cxf (http://cxf.apache.org/)

see jaxws or jaxrs for more.

Answer (score 0):

create web service in a two types but real time applications using jax-ws web services reason for consumer want to send data into  provider.consumer can know the entire information about the provider by seeing its WSDL Document.